# Clojure loop reads one extra

Tags: loops, clojure, stream, lisp

When length is 4 following loop executes 5 times. Reading 5 characters from the stream.

```
(loop [i (.read stream)  result ""  counter length]
    (let [c (char i)]
      (println "=>" c)
      (if (zero? counter)
        result
        (recur (.read stream) (str result c) (dec counter)))))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should test for `zero?` before you do the `read`.  Note that your version will call `read` once even if `length` == 0 to begin with.

```
(loop [result "" counter length]
  (if (zero? counter)
    result
    (let [c (char (.read stream))]
      (println "=>" c )
      (recur (str result c) (dec counter)))))
```

Another way which avoids an explicit `loop`:

```
(apply str 
       (take length 
             (repeatedly #(let [c (char (.read stream))]
                            (println "=>" c) c)))))
```

Comment: So i should add another test before the loop for zero but i still don't get why it is running 5 times? is this the clojure behavior or am i missing something?

Comment: Your version does the read when counter = 4, 3, 2, 1, 0.  That's five iterations.  The first read is done inside the loop bindings vector to set up `i` initially, and the next four reads are done via `recur`.  By the time you test `counter` for `zero?` you've already done one read too many. The version I posted moves the read inside the if-statement, which avoids this problem.  You don't need another test before the loop.

Comment: Step through your loop in your head, you will see where the 5th character comes from.  Basically, repeating the same thing (.read stream) at two places in the loop is a code smell.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know clojure, but it looks to me like you're reading the stream again in "result" form, is this like final in CL ?